# Broken Skip method in let subquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my application there is an issue part that allows questions and responses.  Something like (Pseudo code, as this is actually generated from Entity Framework):

```
class Response
{
  string Author;
  string Comment;
  DateTime Date;
}

class Issue
{
  IEnumerable<Response> Responses;
}
```

We have a summary page where we just want to show the last two responses.  I tried a linq query like this:

```
from issue in db.Issue
let responses = from response in issue.Responses orderby response.Date
select new
{
  Issue = issue,
  Question = responses.FirstOrDefault(),
  Answer = responses.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

But this gives me the error that Skip can only be used on ordered collections.  I checked `responses` and it was an IOrderedEnummerable.  I thought maybe the problem was that it was Enumerable instead of IOrderedQueryable, and saw that this happened because issue.Response is a collection so I switched the let statement to be:

```
let response = from response in db.Responses where response.IssueId = issue.ID // etc.
```

but this did not resolve the issue (but response did become an IOrderedQueryable) so I'm not really sure why entity won't accept the skip here.  If I put the skip in the `let` statement, it works without problem (but then I can't get the first response).  The issue seams to only occur by trying to put a portion of this statement in a variable before using it.

Comment: If response has 10 records Questions will have records 0-9 (10), where Answer will have records 1-9 (9). Because Skip only skips the number of records you designate, It will yield the total records minus the amount you told it to skip (not include).

Comment: Which is fine.  Later in the code I use FirstOrDefault which will take the new first one, i.e. the second one.

Comment: I'm a little confused about whether you want records 0 & 1 or records 8 & 9 from (my previous comment). What if you were to just get the responses from the query, and then manipulate it into the Question and Answer vars outside the query?

Comment: I want the first and the second and I'd like to pull only those back from the database.  Of course I can always just pull everything into memory and sort it there but if I'm going to do that I don't need linq. :)

Comment: You should look into sql select top and the take method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is: how will/should EF translate your query into a SQL statement? There is no straightforward SQL equivalent of Skip(1). Just try to write your query in SQL and you should see what I mean.

If you want an "easy" solution, then just get all responses from the DB and identify the ones you need in code.

If you want to minimize the data being read from the DB, the solutions might range from creating a view to writing a stored procedure to changing your tables so that your tables better reflect the data model in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what's going on here, but wouldn't this be maybe a little simpler:

```
var theResponse = db.Issue.Select(i => new {
    Issue = i,
    Question = i.Responses.FirstOrDefault(),
    Answer = i.Responses.OrderBy(r => r.Date).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
});
```

But this is also weird, because you are getting a full `Issue` object with all of its properties and whatnot, including the `Reponse` objects and stuffing it back into an `Issue` property of your dynamic type beside all of the `Response` objects...

Comment: I'm simplifying a bit.  Actually the select is pulling out all the data into a Dto.  And your simplification won't work for me because I need Question to be the first response sorted by Date and Answer to be the second.